# Is it possible to disable the sizing frame but keep the ability to rotate a 3d graph?

Tags: graphics, cdf-format

I want to be able to rotate the following figure freely as shown.  However, I do not want the frame to be selectable.  You can see that the frame become visible when I click just the right of the object.  It's nice that it can be used to resize the object, but I do not want this. I would rather not have the ability to resize as I do not want the frame visible at all.  Is this possible?  I tried setting the Notebook option Selectable to False. But this does not work.  It disables the frame from becoming visible but then I can't rotate the object.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following: `Style[Graphics3D[Sphere[]], ShowSelection -> False]`