# How can I disable built in selection action for mouse click events?

Tags: graphics3d, eventhandler

I am trying to improve a [demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LocateAPointOnTheEarthsSurface/) that I previously submitted to the Wolfram Demonstration site. That demonstration enables a user to select a position on an Earth globe and see the latitude and longitude of the position. The user can rotate and zoom the globe using sliders. One of the improvements that I would like to make is to use the built-in capabilities of 3D graphics rather than programmatically changing the View* options. I am able to do this, with the below code. Unfortunately, there is an unwelcome side effect:

```
   EventHandler[
    graphic3D,
    {
     "MouseClicked" :>
      (
       loc = 
        IntersectLineAndSphere[
          MousePosition["Graphics3DBoxIntercepts"]][[1]];
       If[loc != {}, pointOnSurfaceCartesian = loc];
       latlon = Cartesian2LatLon[pointOnSurfaceCartesian]
       )
     },
    PassEventsDown -> True
    ]
```

where pointOnSurfaceCartesian is a Control of type None. The full working code is available as a notebook [here](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/fac/Spencer.Rugaber/GlobalSelect.nb).

The side effect is that now, when I click to choose a point on the Earth's surface, the graphic box gets visibly selected.

[image]

I have tried playing with EventHandler, with no success:

- MouseClick vs. MouseDown
- Nested event handlers with PassEventDown -> True vs. Automatic
- Null actions to disable handling

I get various effects from these experiments but none that are what I want.

My top-level question is how I can control event handling in a 3D graphic so that 1) Rotate/Pan/Zoom are handled by the system; 2) Selection is turned off; and Clicking the mouse is handled by my code?

In my explorations, several lower-level questions also arose:

- Is there an "official" list of the system actions taken on user
  events, such as selection and rotate? Is there an API to them that my
  code can use? Is there a programmatic way to disable these actions?
- Also, in my search of previous questions, I found one interesting
  sounding possibility [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109257/changing-the-rotate-behavior-of-a-3d-graphics/109260#109260). It referred to a  Method called
  "RotationControl"->"Globe". It is briefly mentioned in the 
  documentation for Graphics3D. However, I could find no documentation 
  for it or its alternatives ("ArcBall", "TrackBall"). Are these
  described anywhere?

I am running MMa 11.0 on a MacBook Pro with OSX 10.9.5.

Comment: Can not focus right now but it seems to be at least related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132792/5478

Comment: Bingo. It seems to work. I will test it a bit more, but I suggest adding it as an answer.

Comment: @SpencerRugaber You might also consider writing it up as a self-answer. These are *encouraged* on StackExchange sites.

Comment: @SpencerRugaber since I don't have anything more to add it is appropriate to mark it as a duplicate. But, in case it does not really solve your problem, let me know.

Comment: The suggestion by Kuba provides a way for me to solve my direct problem. However it does not really answer my questions about actions associated with event handling. I don't know what the correct protocol is: Do I write up Kuba's suggestion as an answer and close the question, or do I leave it open for a while to see whether anyone addresses the specific questions I listed?